# time penalty for using encapsulation in bytecode?

Tags: java

In Java, I encapsulate fields as a matter of course. Most times, the getters / setters just get or set the field's value without doing any additional processing. Is there an optimization that converts the method call into a direct access in this case or am I getting a performance hit for the encapsulation? My application is a simulation that accesses big arrays a lot and the extra overhead may have an impact on runtime that may be significant so I am wondering whether I need to check this out or I am safe to ignore it?

Comment: The JIT can generally optimize out the method calls. It *might* help to remove them under heavy load, but you shouldn't assume without thoroughly testing.

Comment: but you shouldn't assume without thoroughly testing[²]